# Aspose.PDF Triggers Breakpoint

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017, aspose, aspose.pdf

I implemented **Aspose.Cells** and **Aspose.PDF** into our companies existing application.
While I had some trouble with this (mostly caused by the fact that I tried to implement both APIs into the exat same file which was a bad idea)
I figured out how to make it work more or less.

My Problem now is while **Aspose.Cells** works perfectly fine and doesn't seem to have any unusual behavior **Aspose.PDF** already struggles with setting the license and even when I eventually got this to work I can't even initiate a **Aspose::Pdf::Document**.

So the first totally unusual thing is the way I had to set the License in the Example code given with the Aspose Package and in the official resources the license is set like this.

```
auto lic = System::MakeObject<Aspose::Pdf::License>();
lic->SetlLicense("c:\\Foo\fooproj\\Aspose.Total.C++.lic");
```

This code won't run on my machine and cause the error.

Rough Translation

> food.exe triggered a breakpoint

Original

> food.exe Hat einen Haltepunkt ausgelöst

The same happens when I initialise a *System::String* with a emtpy constructor like this.

```
 auto lic = System::MakeObject<Aspose::Pdf::License>();
 System::String str;
 str.FromUtf8("C:\\foo\fooproj\\Aspose.Total.C++.lic");
 lic->SetLicense(str);
```

BUT if I initialise the *System::String* with an empty String in the first place setting the license seems to work just fine so this works.

```
 auto lic = System::MakeObject<Aspose::Pdf::License>();
 System::String str(u"");
 str.FromUtf8("C:\\Projekte\\Aspose\\Lizens\\Aspose.Total.C++.lic");
 lic->SetLicense(str);
```

If this code above works and I try to make an object from **Aspose::Pdf::Document** this will crash.

```
void Aspose_pdf::helloWorld()
{
  auto doc = System::MakeObject<Aspose::Pdf::Document>();
.....
.....
}
```

I actually have no idea what's going on. I am not using any *using namespace* commands at the moment.
Would be greate if someone had an idea how to fix this.

Edit:
The error occures exactly in smart_ptr.h in the following function.

```
typename std::enable_if<!IsSmartPtr<T>::value, SmartPtr<T> >::type  MakeObject(Args&&... args)
{
    System::Detail::OwnNextObject ownershipSentry;
    T *const object = ::new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    ownershipSentry.CreatedSuccessfully(object);
    return SmartPtr<T>(object);
}
```

in the second line so `T *const object = ::new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);`
is "causing" the error or atleast here the error will ne triggered.

Edit2:

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NSAMxjRAuBVW9ZpCiKZTs5HS3mHTQ6jy/view?usp=sharing) you will find a simple example of how my code looks in general.
I Started with implementing **Aspose.Pdf** into my Programm so I edited my 
Additional Library directories,additional dependencies, additional include directories,preprozessor definitions and my stacksize to fit these settings given in the **Aspose.Pdf** examples.
After this I created my *Aspose_Pdf* class and tested it. worked perferctly so far.
After this I made the same edits to fit **Aspose.Cells** aswell. Also I created a class *Aspose_Cells* and tested it. While this worked now my *Aspose_Pdf* class stoped working. After a little time passed I managed to atleast get the License Activation for *Aspose_Pdf* to work from this point on I had the problems described above.

Additional Dependencies:

```
   ...
    Aspose.PDF_vc141x64d.lib
    aspose_cpp_vc141x64d.lib
    Aspose.Cells.lib
```

Additional Librariedirectories:

```
   ...
    ..\Aspose\Aspose.PDF\lib\Debug
    ..\Aspose\Aspose.Cells\lib64
```

additional Includedirectories

```
 ...
    ..\Aspose\Aspose.PDF\lib\Debug
    ..\Aspose\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib
    ..\Aspose\Aspose.PDF\include\Aspose.Pdf.Cpp
    ..\Aspose\Aspose.Cells\Include
    ..\Aspose\Aspose.Cells\Include\icu\include
    ..\Aspose\Aspose.Cells\Include\boost
```

Comment: Is there any reason for using such a weird way to initialize objects as `System::MakeObject<...`?

Comment: @SergeyShevchenko I actually don't know why this is done but I haven't figured out another way to initialize these objects properly.
I Used the Example code given with the API Package and some of the references from the offical website.

Comment: Would you please share narrowed down sample application while mentioning the steps to reproduce it so that we may try to reproduce it and assist you accordingly. **PS:** I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @FarhanRaza Thanks for your response.
Please see my *Edit2:* I hope this time I managed to give all the information you needed

Comment: We are looking into your requirements as you have reported with details over Aspose forums. We will share our findings with you soon. Kindly follow up in respective thread.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard about **Aspose.Pdf** neither I know how does `System::MakeObject<` work. But for me it looks that all the code might be simplified to next:

```
Aspose::Pdf::License^ lic = gcnew Aspose::Pdf::License();
System::String^ str = "C:\\foo\\fooproj\\Aspose.Total.C++.lic";
lic->SetLicense(str);
```

When it comes to `Pdf.Document` the initialization might look like this:

```
Aspose::Pdf::Document^ doc = gcnew Aspose::Pdf::Document();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answere. unfortunately I can't use this code samples since I use c++ not c++-cli. I don't know who and why this tag was changed I just know it was a mistake and I couldn't even approve it, it was just there ... but thanks for your time in the firstplace